# Unable to access Sitecore Publish service get request

Tags: sitecore-api, publishing-service

We have a custom dashboard for monitoring all servers health check, as part that we have one component to display publishing statistics (Here we display ongoing, queued publish items). Now we are using publish service to publish data from one database to another database.

We tried using `Web API` to get response from publishing service (
`https://{hosturl}/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/%7B00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7D/All?sourceDatabase=master`  ) but getting `403 forbidden or unauthorized exception`.

Please help us here any other way to get response from above URL.

Answer (score 3):

Usually anonymous users are not allowed to access Sitecore RESTful API for security reasons. You should send a POST request to `/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login` to authenticate a user before calling any other `/sitecore/api/ssc/...` API method.

By default Sitecore API is configured to use session-based authorization, but if you want to use token authorization then change the setting `Sitecore.Services.Token.Authorization.Enabled` to `true`.
All settings related to API security and authorization are listed in the file `/App_Config/Sitecore/Services.Client/Sitecore.Services.Client.config`, though be careful and consider application security before changing any of them.

There is also an alternative way to get publishing queue information. You can call Publishing Service API directly and get the list of queued jobs by calling  the API method:

```
https://{publishing-service-host}/api/publishing/jobqueue
```

If there is an active publishing job, it will be returned by the method:

```
https://{publishing-service-host}/api/publishing/activejob
```

You can call the following API method to the list of recent jobs:

```
https://{publishing-service-host}/api/publishing/jobhistory?skip=0&top=10
```

Comment: How to get recent jobs ?

Comment: @Reddy you can call `https://{publishing-service-host}/api/publishing/jobhistory?skip=0&top=10` to get the list of recent jobs, parameters `skip` and `top` are used for pagination. I added these details to the answer above too.